# How can I change size of textBox in MVC?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Change of size doesn't work :(

```
@Html.TextBox("Imie", new { @class = "boxx" })
```

Css:

```
.boxx{
    height : 400px;
    width : 500px;
}
```

[the class = "boxx" is wrote in textBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRObY.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look [at the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textbox(v=vs.118).aspx) (or intellisense) and you will see the available overloads.
Try

```
@Html.TextBox("Imie", null, new { @class = "boxx" })
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try below code:

```
@Html.TextBox("Imie", null, new { @class = "boxx" })
```

3rd value is for `HTML` attribute.

Hope it solved your issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can also try Inline css if you want to

```
@Html.TextBox(x => x.testBox, new { style = "width: 20px;" })
```